# Can Meteor handle nested dependencies?

Tags: javascript, meteor

If the cursor that my Meteor autorun function depends on is itself dependent, Will Meteor create and save a new Computation every time the innermost-dependency changes?

What if one autorun function calls Deps.autorun on another function?

```
Session.set('fooVal', 33);
myComputation = Deps.autorun(function() { 
  if (typeof(myComputation) !== 'undefined')
    myComputation.stop(); // Is this needed to prevent Computation accumulation?
  var foos = BarCollection.find({foo:Session.get('fooVal')}; 
  /* Do stuff with foos */
});
Session.set('fooVal', 33);
Session.set('fooVal', 34);
Session.set('fooVal', 35);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor can use reactive data as a key or value in a Collection query. Read the [Reactivity](http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity) section of the docs carefully.

Autorun functions may be nested without memory leaks. If the inner autorun block is invalidated, only the inner block is re-run. If the outer autorun block is invalidated both autorun blocks are re-run.

Important to understand:

- Deps.autorun creates and returns a Computation object.
- The Computation object keeps keeps track of all reactive data sources that the function depends on.
- When any one of the reactive data sources changes, the entire function is re-run.

Comment: If you need for customization such as have an customized autorun run only when a particular dependency changes have a look at http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency